# Drive script to take any upload to one folder and automatically copy it to several others?

Tags: google-apps-script, google-drive-api

I am a teacher and am currently using drive to distribute files amongst shared folders for my 4 classes. As of now, if I want to upload or share a document I have to do it 4 different times through the apps I use.

My question is: Is there a script or some other way that I can upload to a specific folder, and whatever I upload can automatically be moved into the four separate shared folders?  I still need the folders to be separate and each of the 4 folders.

Thank you so much for your help.

Comment: Not an answer, but have a look at http://gcdc2013-student-drive.appspot.com/ which might give you an alternative approach